# No Method Error ( accessing method inside async function )

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am working on an Zappa app and have encountered what I believe a bottleneck in my JavaScript knowledge. The issue is that I can't find a way to access a function inside an async function.

When I am in CoffeeScript, I remember using `that = @` or `( that = this )` kind of works. I also tried the `=>` instead of `->` but yielded no success.

This is the error message: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'convertUploadedImage'`

How can I overcome this?

The issue is on:

```
        .on "end", () ->
          file.end()
          console.log "log inside"
          console.log that.constructor.name
          that.convertUploadedImage file
```

Thank in advance.

Whole code ( or at least what I think matters ):

```
{@app} = require('./node_modules/zappajs') ->
  @post "/collage/upload", (req, res) ->
    # We might be uploading two types of files
    #   1. web form 
    #   2. as a link
    #

    # Check for the upload URL to exist
    url = req.body.upload_url # if req.body.upload_url
    console.log "URL is - #{url}"
    # URL is present - Retrieve the proper file
    if url 
      # setting up for download
      http     = require 'http'
      fileName = url.split('/').pop()
      file     = fs.createWriteStream __dirname + "/public/images/uploads/temp/#{fileName}"

      that = @
      console.log that.constructor.name
      # download the file
      request = http.get "#{url}", ( res ) ->
        res.on "data", (data) ->
          file.write data
        .on "end", () ->
          file.end()
          console.log "log inside"
          console.log that.constructor.name
          that.convertUploadedImage file

    # URL is not present
    else
      file = req.files.files[0]
      @convertUploadedImage file

  convertUploadedImage: ( file, deleteOriginal = false ) ->    
    # Checking file type
    console.log file.type
```

Comment: From the code you have posted, it doesn't look like convertUploadedImage belongs to any object. Have you tried calling it directly (`convertUploadedImage file`)?

Comment: Hi Adam, well I forgot to mention in the question, in the else part `@convertUploadedImage file` works... I am not much in the JS but I thought it should work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this part of the docs (http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow), the fat arrow should work:

```
  request = http.get "#{url}", ( res ) =>
    res.on "data", (data) ->
      file.write data
    .on "end", () =>
      file.end()
      console.log "log inside"
      console.log that.constructor.name
      @convertUploadedImage file
```